# Break row out into multiple rows then collapse values back

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK - I have a table - where I can have a row with multiple quanties - what I need to be able to do is to take all rows where there is a qty > 1 - create multiple rows - one for each qty - perform a simple calculation against each row - say multiply the val field by 2 - and then roll the rows back up into another temp table or something...?

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    code varchar(10), 
    codeStatus varchar, 
    qty int, 
    val money)
        INSERT INTO @table 
   SELECT 
   '12345', 
   'T',
    2,
    1
```

Comment: Huh? You need to provide more details. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What attempts to solve the problem have you made so far?

Comment: your question is quite unclear...can you elaborate???

Comment: OK - let me clarify - I really just need to take a row - where an item might have multiple QTY - and say for each QTY on the row - e.g.2 - insert the new rows into a new table variable - so if I have a row with qty 2 - I need the original row broken out into 2 rows.  If the qty is 5 - then 5 rows... Make sense?  I was trying some form of loop - but got lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A numbers table is your friend here.

The join against the numbers table effectively performs your expansion.  The code below is essentially just the 'expansion' part of your question.  After this its trivial to apply whatever transformations you need, push into temp table and so on.

```
/*
--create numbers table if don't already have one...
select top 1000000 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
into dbo.Numbers
from   master..spt_values t1 
       cross join master..spt_values t2
*/

DECLARE @table TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1),code varchar(10), codeStatus varchar, qty int, val money)
INSERT INTO @table SELECT '12345', 'T', 2, 1

select t.id, t.code, t.codeStatus, t.qty, t.val
from @table t
     inner join dbo.Numbers n on n.N <= t.qty
```

Comment: That looks good - but I need to do something else to my rows first - so just need it simplified for now - 

So if I have - '12345', 'T', 2, 1 I need to seperate the rows to become:

Row 1: '12345', 'T', 1, 1

Row 2: '12345', 'T', 1, 1

Comment: Ok, I've amended to simplify it as far as is possible. The code will give you your row expansion exactly as per your comment. Good luck.